# glClearBuffer takes 1 second on a Geforce 9500GT

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, frame-buffer

These 2 lines (in C# using OpenTK) seem to cause 1 second lag every frame on a machine with a Geforce 9500 GT

```
GL.ClearBuffer(ClearBuffer.Color, 0, new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 }); // accum
GL.ClearBuffer(ClearBuffer.Color, 1, new float[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }); // reveal (only red)
```

The framebuffer in question has 2 color attachments (Rgba16f and R16), and one depth attachement. The framebuffer status after setup indicates no problems.

This is also just one of 3 framebuffers that are cleared every frame - only this one turns the my game into a diashow. There is no such problem on any other card I've tested. Before clearing both color attachment are bound using

```
DrawBuffersEnum[] bufs = new DrawBuffersEnum[] { DrawBuffersEnum.ColorAttachment0, DrawBuffersEnum.ColorAttachment1 };
GL.DrawBuffers(2, bufs);
```

How could a very particular gfx card be so slow in clearing 2 color attachments? o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I used ushorts in one of my VBOs to save a bit on memory, but seems to be very costly when doing lookups on certain AMD cards. After switching back to full integers the performance drop was gone.